# How should one handle file path while hosting a Go project in Google App Engine ? open templates/index.html: no such file or directory

Tags: google-app-engine, go, deployment

I am trying to deploy a simple go language code on Google's app engine. This is the code I am trying to deploy. 
https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/golang-samples/tree/master/appengine/go11x/static

main.go

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "html/template"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "os"
    "path/filepath"
    "time"
)

var (
    indexTmpl = template.Must(
        template.ParseFiles(filepath.Join("templates", "index.html")),
    )
)

func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/", indexHandler)

    // Serve static files out of the public directory.
    // By configuring a static handler in app.yaml, App Engine serves all the
    // static content itself. As a result, the following two lines are in
    // effect for development only.
    public := http.StripPrefix("/public", http.FileServer(http.Dir("public")))
    http.Handle("/public/", public)

    port := os.Getenv("PORT")
    if port == "" {
        port = "8080"
        log.Printf("Defaulting to port %s", port)
    }

    log.Printf("Listening on port %s", port)
    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(fmt.Sprintf(":%s", port), nil))
}

// indexHandler uses a template to create an index.html.
func indexHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    if r.URL.Path != "/" {
        http.NotFound(w, r)
        return
    }
    type indexData struct {
        Logo        string
        Style       string
        RequestTime string
    }
    data := indexData{
        Logo:        "/public/gcp-gopher.svg",
        Style:       "/public/style.css",
        RequestTime: time.Now().Format(time.RFC822),
    }
    if err := indexTmpl.Execute(w, data); err != nil {
        log.Printf("Error executing template: %v", err)
        http.Error(w, "Internal server error", http.StatusInternalServerError)
    }
}
```

When I deploy this code using  `gcloud app deploy` and use the browser to load the webpage, I see error

```
2019-08-24 06:32:19 default[]  "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500
2019-08-24 06:32:20 default[]  panic: open templates/index.html: no such file or directory    goroutine 1 [running]:  html/template.Must(0x0, 0x800800, 0xc000078f90, 0
x0)     /usr/local/go/src/html/template/template.go:372 +0x54
```

My app.yaml file looks like this. It has static mentioned but nothing about templates.

```
runtime: go111
handlers:
# Configure App Engine to serve any static assets.
- url: /public
  static_dir: public
# Use HTTPS for all requests.
- url: /.*
  secure: always
  redirect_http_response_code: 301
  script: auto
```

Question:
How do I handle templates and other small files that I want the application to read? Mine is a toy application so I do not need cloud storage or any such solution. I just want to read from a (local) directory.

Comment: The sample code you are using is correct, I was able to deploy it and it worked for me. Have you tried downloading the files from the repository again and trying to deploy it?

Comment: I didn't try it under the assumption it will not change anything. Since you suggested, I will download again and let you know how it goes. It is a weekend project for me. so I will take 3-4 days to post the result here. Thanks very much. If it helps, I cloned the repo and cd-ed into static directory. There I did gcloud app deploy. Did you also do the same thing? Is there a way to check the folder structure of the deployment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So... I tested this deployment in 3 different ways and what I found was that:

1. Directly cloning the repo with `git clone`, `cd` to the **static** folder, and deploying from there, reproduced the issue, but only if I did it from my Google Cloud Shell.

   **a.** I later found out that the Go version I had in the Cloud Shell was the Go 1.12.

   **b.** I created a new VM instance to test it from a fresh Go 1.11 environment and the same process worked like a treat.
2. The same process as the above, but instead of deploying from the static, I moved its content to a different directory and then I deployed it from there.

   **a.** This worked in the VM instance and in the Cloud Shell.
3. As suggested in the [Quickstart for Go 1.11 in the App Engine Standard Environment](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/go111/quickstart), I downloaded the sample code using the `go get` command, `cd` to the static folder and deployed from there.

   **a.** This also worked in both environments.

My suggestion is to always try to download Google's golang samples using the `go get` command, as it is suggested in the guides and it did not mess with the App Engine deployment in the tests I made.

It is also important to mention that both environments had the same Cloud SDK version, which is the 259.

Comment: Thanks. I played around with what you suggested. It seems like when you do `cd golang-samples/appengine/go11x/static`,it fails because (somehow) deployment thinks the root directory to put templates and static(s) is golang-samples(i.e. as a sibling of appengine). When I do `cp -r golang-samples/tree/master/appengine/go11x/static ~/staticmodified; cd ~/staticmodified; gcloud app deploy `, it works very well. If it helps, I also copied go11x/static to $GOPATH/src, there also it worked well.

Comment: Thans for being so responsive and following up with answer!